# What is the purpose of ?() => void in a function parameter

Tags: javascript, flowtype

The following function exists in [Facebook's open source F8 Application](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/805e3afbf052f019db218e564ebe80fbaed756f9/js/store/configureStore.js#L48)

```
async function configureStore(onComplete: ?() => void) {
  // function body
}
```

In the `configureStore` parameters, what is the purpose of `onComplete: ?() => void`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Flow syntax signifying that `configureStore` takes an optional callback parameter `onComplete`, that can be `null`.

However, the `// @flow` annotation is missing in this file. Files using Flow type checking should include this annotation at the top of the file before any code.

There are two parts to this annotation:

**1.** `() => void` denotes a Flow Function type. In the above case, the `onComplete` parameter is a function with no arguments and return type `void`.

**2.** `?` denotes a Maybe type. In the above case, `onComplete` is an optional parameter.

> Maybe types accept the provided type as well as `null` or `undefined`.

**Note: order matters.** If `?` was instead *before* `:`, (ie: `onComplete?:`), then the function would accept the provided type and `undefined`, but not `null`.

**Reference:**

- [`@flow`](https://flow.org/en/docs/usage/#toc-prepare-your-code-for-flow)
- [Function Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/)
- [Maybe Type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/)